# How can I capture data from the 'tooltip' in Fusioncharts that shows date/time?

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts

So, if you go to https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/fusiontime/getting-started/create-your-multi-variate-chart-in-fusiontime and hover your mouse on the chart, you will see a tooltip that shows a startdate and an enddate and these dates update for each new point in the chart. Such as in this tooltip below.

[Fusioncharts tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLFcb.png)

I am looking to capture these updating dates and display a picture inside a div if it falls between these 2 dates.

These values update depending on which sample point it is within the data, it applies some simple algorithm within it to decide the duration between startDate and endDate but these dates are provided with a JSON file to the charts in this format:

..... [ "1/4/2011", 16.448 ], [ "1/5/2011", 272.736 ], ....

Where and what is it that I should look for that reflects these updating values? Is there a variable in the framework? You may or may not know about Fusioncharts but at some level, this problem boils down to being somewhat generic such as

"How to locate the variables within the Fusioncharts framework that reflect these dates from the data for each sample point?"

Any help is appreciated.

This is the link to Fusioncharts framework as CDN:
https://cdn.fusioncharts.com/fusioncharts/latest/fusioncharts.js
https://cdn.fusioncharts.com/fusioncharts/latest/fusioncharts.timeseries.js

I am not sure what is it that I should even look for so I haven't been able to try it out

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) Please post all code necessary to understand your problem in the question itself.

Comment: I don't have a code snippet to reference to for this particular question. I am asking with reference to a chart object which I can't provide on the same page and a framework which has thousands of lines of code. And that is why, I provided links in my question.

Comment: You can reduce the data to only a handful of data entries. The framework might also not relevant for the question, you can read the documentation yourself. Please edit your question so that it is clear what you are asking and what your exact problem is.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, what you're saying is true in general. Although, over here, there is no data that I can reduce. In order to make the reader familiar with the interactivity of Fusioncharts, I have to provide a link, there's no other way if they don't know what I'm talking about. And yes, I can remove the links to the framework as a CDN if it really doesn't help anybody to answer the question.

I would appreciate if you could point out which part of the question is not clear or seem confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `toolText` property to set any tooltip text you want.
It should be something like this:

```
const dataset1 = [];
const dataset2 = [];

for (const row of data) {
  dataset1.push({
    value: row.value1,
    toolText: formatTooltipText(row.myDate1),
  });
  dataset2.push({
    value: row.value2,
    toolText: formatTooltipText(row.myDate2),
  });
}

const chart = {
  chart: myChartConfig,
  categories: myChartCategories,
  dataset: [
    {
      seriesname: mySeriesName1,
      color: myColor1,
      data: dataset1,
    },
    {
      seriesname: mySeriesName2,
      color: myColor2,
      data: dataset2,
    },
  ],
};
return chart;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think tootText is a property is a construct common to all(or most) charting libraries and not just fusioncharts. I havent' looked into it much but that's just my guess. I wonder where can I learn more about this?

Comment: @Sa'adMuHammad Check [here](https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-attributes/area2d).

Answer (score 0):

FusionTime allows you to customize the tooltip of the chart. All the customizations to the tooltip can be made using the newly introduced tooltip object under dataSource.

```
    "dataSource": {
    "tooltip": {
        "enabled": Boolean,
        "style": {
            "container": {
                "padding": "10px"
            },
            "text": {
                "font-size": "16"
            },
            "header": {
                "font-color": "#ff0000"
                },
            "body": {
                "font-color": "#ff00ff"
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Refferd doc - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/fusiontime/fusiontime-component/tooltip-in-fusiontime#style-definition

To customize the tooltip content - A new attribute property inside tooltip object named **toolText**, this attribute through the use of macros accepts input to custom tooltip content.

```
tooltip: {
    enabled: "true",
    toolText: "<div style='color: #393939;'><img src = 'https://logodownload.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/nasdaq-logo.png' width ='125' height ='30' /><hr>StartDate <br>EndDate<br> </div>"
  },
```

To know more about this feature please refer - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/fusiontime/fusiontime-component/tooltip-in-fusiontime#customise-tooltip-content

Here is demo fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/85f1uhd0/

Hope this would help.